# echoerr された内容を Vim の終了後に確認したい

Tags: vim

`:qa` や `:qa!` して Vim を終了する際，エンターキーを叩いてから画面が消えるまでの一瞬の間に， 稀に terminal の下端に赤色がちらつくことがあるのに気づきました．場所と色からいって何かが `echoerr` されたのに違いないのですが，再現条件が不明な上メッセージを読めないので何が起こったのかさっぱりわかりません．

Vim の終了後にも `echoerr` の内容を辿れるようにすることは可能でしょうか．

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vimrc に

```
set verbosefile=/tmp/vim.log
set verbose=20
```

と書いて実行するか

```
vim -V20/tmp/vim.log foobar
```

といった具合に実行すると `/tmp/vim.log` に詳細なログが出力されるので、そこからエラーと思しき部分を探すのが良いと思います。

Comment: `verbose=20` であれば `Every executed Ex command` も記録されるということですね．無責任にも本当に `echoerr` さえ見られればよければ `-V0` (… `:h 'verbose'` に記述を見つけられませんでしたが)で大丈夫，という理解で大丈夫でしょうか．echo された内容と autocmd の一覧辺りが出力されている？

Comment: V の値はやろうとされている内容でご自身で変えられると良いと思います。
例えば echoerr しているはずなのにされない、であれば echoerr しているか確認する為に V20 を、単に表示されたけどすぐ消えたので見えないという事であれば V0 でも構わないと思います。

Answer (score 2):

screen を起動して `C-a :log` でログを記録しながら vim を使うというのはいかがでしょう。
tmux でも同様のことはできそうですけど、私には使えないので他の方の回答に期待。